# WPF IDataErrorInfo and NHibernate Validation - how to trigger a Validate?

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, validation, mvvm, binding

I recently plugged the NHibernate validation into my app, I've decorated the properties of my domain objects with the NHibernate attributes as so ...

```
    [NotEmpty, Length(Min = 1, Max = 40)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

I've also implemented IDataErrorInfo on my Domain Object  ...

```
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            var result = new ValidatorEngine().Validate(this);
            _invalidValues = result.Where(x => x.PropertyName == columnName).Select(x => x.Message);
            return _invalidValues.FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

The XAML looks like this

```
 <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Path=Entity.Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}" ></TextBox>
```

My issue is that when I create a new instance of my Domain object then the validate is not being called, as effectively the properties (such as the Description in my example) have not changed.

I was going to write a method to use reflection and set the properties to what they are already equal to in order to trigger the validate, but this dosnt seem a particularly efficient approach!!

Can someone put me back on track please?

Cheers,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because the properties were Null and I needed another NHibernate validation decorator to take account of that (NotNullNotEmpty) rather than the NotEmpty I had used.

```
 [NotNullNotEmpty, Length(Min = 1, Max = 40)]
 public string Description { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Paul Stovell](http://paulstovell.net/) for has an excellent article for [validation of business objects](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DelegateBusinessObjects.aspx)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DelegateBusinessObjects.aspx